# Facebook recommendation box display over other items

Tags: html, facebook-recommendations

I'm using the Facebook recommendation box in my site www.letralia.com. It worked correctly until a few weeks ago. Now, the box is displaying over other items in the page.

What is wrong?

Thanks in advance,

J

Answer (score 1):

Just to let you know that this is happening in other places. My site (thisisxbox.com) is also having the problem of the recommendations box overlapping (despite being inside a div css inlne-block etc) and also randomly vanishing. It has been reported on the facebook developers site as a bug because the issue is coming from them and not anything you're doing with styling.

It's been picked up as a moderate issue and facebook are looking into the error...

Comment: Can you give a link to the report on developer site?

Answer (score 0):

try insert some content before the end of 'div' where the facebook plugin is inserted.. or maybe clear can help.

```
<div class="avisoderecha"><INSERTED FB PLUGIN CODE><span>&nbsp;</span></div>
```

or

```
<div class="avisoderecha"><INSERTED FB PLUGIN CODE><div style="clear:left;"></div></div>
```

or set fixed height for that box

```
<div class="avisoderecha" style="height:460px;"><INSERTED FB PLUGIN CODE></div>
```

Comment: :( Another problem... The recommendation box disappear after a 20 seconds. :(

Comment: Yeah, I can see. Mhm, my firefox firebug plugin console says: 'fb:recommendations failed to resize in 45s' all.js...9378414 (row 49)

Comment: :( Thanks, anyway. I'll keep trying before delete it.

Comment: Try insert FB code in other available formats (instead of iframe -> HTML5 or XFBML or change old iframe code for new) here [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations/)